# Embedding zip file in word which is "Restricted"

Tags: microsoft-word, zip

i have a word document which is protected. (Protect Document -> Restrict Access -> read access to all users). This is to stop users from copying the contents. So far it's fine. But when I'm trying to embedded a zip file in it, the other users who have only read access for that document couldn't able to access this zip file.(They can access the word document) But not the zip file in it. Clicking actions on the zip icon doesn't yield any result. But when i remove the "IRM" read only access from it, others are able to retrieve the zip file.
Is there any work around for it? So that i can have Restriction on the word document and embed the zip file.

Comment: Your question isn't clear please clarify it.

Comment: @Ramhound edited!